# Floating Action Button show on keypad

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, floating-action-button

I want to show **Floating Action Button** top of the soft keypad. 
I already used

**android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"**

but thats not suitable with my layout, so i set **adjustpan** and then how to show FAB on the keypad.

Comment: show your some code??

Answer (score 0):

root view in layout xml should contain android:fitsSystemWindows="true" property Or programmatically include

```
      this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams‌​.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_R‌​ESIZE);
```

Comment: i dont want to use adjustResize  because my layout contains multiple edit text when i set adjustResize and click on edittext of last row then focus chnage last to secong rows edit text

Comment: use Edittext inside Scrollview ..like this  <Scrollview>
    <RelativeLayout>
        <View/>
        <EditText/>
        <other stuff.../>
    </RelativeLayout>
</Scrollview>

Comment: that view bind in recyclerview